# From which endpoint and how does C read the variables?

Tags: c, pointers

I was messing around with pointers in C and was trying to read values from the same address using different types of pointers. First I created a double variable and assigned the number 26 to it.
`double g = 26;`
like so. And then I assigned `g`'s address to a void pointer `void *vptr = &g;`. after that, I tried to read the value at the address of g as a float by type-casting.
`float *atr = (float*) (vptr);`. When I tried to print the value of `*atr` it gave me `0.000000`. Then i used pointer to a character since characters are 1 byte and tried to see values of those 8 bytes one by one.

```
char *t;
t = (char*) vptr;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    printf("%x t[%d]: %d\n",t+i , i, t[i]);
}
```

it gave me this output

```
ffffcbe9 t[1]: 0
ffffcbea t[2]: 0
ffffcbeb t[3]: 0
ffffcbec t[4]: 0
ffffcbed t[5]: 0
ffffcbee t[6]: 58
ffffcbef t[7]: 64
```

Then I checked binary representation of `g` which is `01000000 00111010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000` using [this](https://www.binaryconvert.com/) website.
When I convert every byte to decimal individually, first byte becomes 64 and the second is 58.
So it was basically reversed. Then I tried to read as a float again but this time i shifted the address.
`atr = (float*) (vptr+4);`. I didn't know how many bytes it would shift but coincidentally i discovered that it shifts by one just like char pointers.
This time i printed as `printf("%f\n",*atr);` and now it gave me `2.906250`.
When I checked it's binary representation it was `01000000 00111010 00000000 00000000` which is the first half of the variable `g`. So I am kind of confused how C is reading values from addresses since it looks like  c reads the values from right-end and when i add positive numbers to addresses it shifts towards left-end. I am sorry for any spelling or grammatical mistakes.

Comment: This is entirely platform (processor) dependent. Read up on big and little endian. Nice job playing around with this sort of stuff. This is a great way to learn!

Comment: @EugeneSh. I read it as a question about how memory layout of numbers works. OP is wondering why the bytes are reversed. The only pointer question was the increment size of `void *`, which they discovered to be 1.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I am talking about this part: *I didn't know how many bytes it would shift but coincidentally i discovered that it shifts by one just like char pointers*. But yeah, it is `void*`, misread the code. To the OP: pointer arithmetic on `void*` is GNU extension and is not legal in standard C (well, in fact most of the things you are doing here are not legal in standard C and lead to undefined behavior :) ).

Comment: @MadPhysicist: It is not processor dependent; it is C-implementation dependent. Given any processor, a C implementation can be implemented on it that provides whatever byte ordering is desired.

Comment: @EricPostpischil. Sure. But given that most C implementations use the native ordering, that's important too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order in which the bytes of an scalar object are stored in C are implementation-defined, per C 2018 6.2.6.1 2. (Array elements are of course stored in ascending order by index, and members of structures are in order of declaration, possibly with padding between them.)

The behavior of using `*atr` after `float *atr = (float*) (vptr);` is not defined by the C standard, due to the aliasing rules in C 2018 6.5 7. It is defined to examine the bytes through a `char` lvalue, as you did with `t[i]`, although which bytes are which is implementation-defined per above.

A proper way to reinterpret some bytes of a `double` as a `float` is to copy them in byte-by-byte, which you can do with manual code using a `char *` or simply `float f; memcpy(&f, &g, sizeof f);`. (`memcpy` is specified to work as if by copying bytes, per C 2018 7.24.2.1 2.) This will of course only reinterpret the low-addressed bytes of the `double` as a `float`, which has two problems:

- The low-address bytes may not be the ones that contain the most significant bytes of the `double`.
- `float` and `double` commonly use different formats, and the difference is not simply that `float` has fewer bits in the significand (the fraction portion). The exponent field is also a different width and has a different encoding bias. So reinterpreting the `double` this way generally will not give you a `float` that has about the same value as a `double`.

> I didn't know how many bytes it would shift but coincidentally i discovered that it shifts by one just like char pointers.

Supporting arithmetic on `void *` is a GCC extension that is, as far as I know, needless. When offsets are added to or subtracted from `void *`, GCC does arithmetic as if it were a `char *`. This appears to be needless because one can do the desired arithmetic simply by using a `char *` instead of a `void *`, so the extension does not provide any new function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So using memcpy function is like type-casting I suppose. But does reading the address as if there was a different type of variable have any actual benefits to binary arithmetics or performance in any program?